# Jquery Returning Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I am using "Select2 Jquery" plugin. For the dropdown select form item, it searches in "Select" items and if it did not find any result, **returns** a value as below:

```
 $("#PROJECTID").select2({
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 4,
        **formatNoMatches: function () { return "no such a value"; },**
    });
```

I am trying to show a partial view in the returning value. I am using ASP.net MVC framework. How can i call a action or show a partial view as a return value?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the jQuery `load` function to call your action which returns the Partial View.

```
// select whatever container you plan to load the Partial View into
$('your selector').load(@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController"));
```

If you already have the action method setup to return the Partial View than that's all that is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have tried the below code but not succesfull .. It writes undefined since it expected a string value i think.            formatNoMatches: function () {

                $(".select2-no-results").css("border", "3px solid red");
              
            },

Comment: @modulerica Right `formatNoMatches` expects a string as the return type from the function.  So why are you trying to show a partial view with it?